Test project not finding my test dll when running VSTest
I have an azure pipline and part of the yaml file is for the regression tests, so the code below works good but I do not like hard coded paths, as we all know these can change over time.
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Regression Public'
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'  
    testSelector: testAssemblies
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.dll
    testFiltercriteria: 'Priority=1|TestCategory=RegressionPublic'

As I say the above works nice, the tests are found and they run. But what I want to do is use a variable to remove the hard coded element. The code below runs but the tests are not found
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Regression Public'
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'  
    testSelector: testAssemblies
    testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*Regression*.dll
        !**\*KevTestWork.Regression.dll
        !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'  
    testFiltercriteria: 'Priority=1|TestCategory=RegressionPublic'

Now in the build task which runs prior to this test task I see these statements
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\KevTestWork.Regression\obj\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.dll" to "C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.dll".
Copying reference assembly from "obj\Release\net6.0\refint\KevTestWork.Regression.dll" to "D:\a\1\s\KevTestWork.Regression\obj\Release\net6.0\ref\KevTestWork.Regression.dll".
KevTestWork.Regression -> C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.dll
Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\KevTestWork.Regression\obj\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.pdb" to "C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.pdb".

So my question is is there a built-in azure variable I can use instead of my hard-coded line?
Thanks in advance for any answers

How many assemblies that match **\*Regression*.dll are there in the solution? And why you are using KevTestWork.Regression.dll assembly in your first task but excluding it in the second task?

There is only 1 assembly that will match **Regression.dll. The 2 sample tasks I have shown are the same task, the first is hard coded the second is not.

@Kev The cause of the issue could be that the Vstest task is using wrong search folder. You need to change the  vstest task searchFolder from searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'  to searchFolder: 'C:\KevTestWork'.


is there a built-in azure variable I can use instead of my hard-coded line?

Yes, you can (and should!) use a predefined variable such as $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), which is the default value of searchFolder.
Instead of:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Regression Public'
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'  
    testSelector: testAssemblies
    testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*Regression*.dll
        !**\*KevTestWork.Regression.dll
        !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'  
    testFiltercriteria: 'Priority=1|TestCategory=RegressionPublic'

Try the following:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Regression Public'
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'  
    testSelector: testAssemblies
    testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*Regression*.dll
        !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'  
    testFiltercriteria: 'Priority=1|TestCategory=RegressionPublic'

Notes:

!**\*KevTestWork.Regression.dll should be removed otherwise it would exclude KevTestWork.Regression.dll assembly from the tests
searchFolder is using the default value ($(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)), so it can be ommited


So I have tried re-running the tests with the changes advised above and once again I get this message.
Source filter: *Regression.dll,!\obj**
##[warning]No test sources found matching the given filter '*Regression*.dll,!*\obj**'
Even though the build shows this
Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\KevTestWork.Regression\obj\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.dll" to "C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.dll".
Now very confused

@Kev try **\*Regression.dll instead of **\*Regression*.dll. Also, double-check the assemblies are somewhere inside $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), which in your case seems to be something like D:\a\1\s\

CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\KevTestWork.Regression\obj\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.dll" to "C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0\KevTestWork.Regression.dll".

From this log, it seems that you have changed the output location to C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0\ for the project. For example, using property argument '-property:OutDir="C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0"' in the build task can change the output location.
In this case, in the VSTest task, you should change the searchFolder to C:\KevTestWork instead of '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)', which is D:\a\1\s.
If you want to use variable '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' as searchFolder, please don't change the default output location.
My test yaml:
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '-property:OutDir="C:\KevTestWork\Release\net6.0"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*Regression*.dll
        !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: 'C:\KevTestWork'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


Test result:


